# I am heaving trouble in uploading the static files to the Django app. What i am missing i don't understand

Tags: django, web, web-development-server

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

{% load static %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

## Template homepage

{% endblock %}

Comment: Please could you specify more your problem

Comment: First, i am using settings : 
  
  `STATIC_URL = "/static/"
  `STATICFILES_DIR = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
  LOGIN_URL = "account:login"
  LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "public:index"
  LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "public:index"       
Secondly i have made a separate folder named as Static where i have placed these files(css,js and images). I have even added the name in Installed apps section 'django.contrib.staticfiles'. Now the console is giving 404 for every file i load. Is this issue with version of Django ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not showing your settings.py code, but a solution could be to configure static support, more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

remember that you must have a static folder created, since this is where django will look for the static files, now it is to create an html file which will be our base:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    {% block title %}{% endblock %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styled.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

and using our base html file you should do the following:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Your title{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- Your content -->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: i am doing settings accordingly as you did mentioned. Will you please look into my settings.py code where i am doing blunder. I have already shared code.

Comment: in your case i would:

Comment: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'public:index'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'account:login'

Comment: remove login url

Comment: Still console is unable to load the JS and image files which i want to import.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'website.apps.accounts',]

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIR = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
LOGIN_URL = "account:login"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "public:index"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "public:index"
```